# It's friday in Iceland

Tags: discussion, fun

Oh hi there.

For the past 5 months or so I've been studying Computer Science at the University of Reykjavik. The last exam of the first year is tomorrow so we are going to get wasted viking style tomorrow night.

There is a possibility of ash fallout in the capital city today. So we were asked to turn up the temperature of our homes (prevents tiny particles from entering the home due to higher pressure inside than outside).

And I got my SO T-Shirt today. It cost me 14$ for the shirt, 15$ for the shipping and 17$ for the awesome import tax we have here. But so worth it.

How are you today?

Oh and the [captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyxxv.png) for this post was pretty funny

Comment: I'm super! Thanks for asking!

Comment: Can you post pics of what it looks like to get wasted Viking style?

Comment: I see you're attempting to justify your absence from the metaverse by using education as an excuse.

Comment: @snicker yes i am

Comment: @squillman if there are any surviving cameras, sure.

Comment: You have returned! Meta misses your Icelandic viking powers.

Comment: @Olafur, so... were there any surviving cameras?

Comment: Almost: http://i.imgur.com/FqkOA.jpg

Answer (score 6):

The viking is back! Unbelievable!

I thought you guys died out. Now I'm feeling sick!

Comment: Just popped into to say hi. I'll probably be back this summer. Vikings never die btw.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure someone needs to register http://isitfridayin.com and script it.  Preferably it'll also serve dynamic images so one can use, for instance, http://isitfridayin.com/iceland.png in their posts.

Comment: http://bit.ly/8ZMPv8

Comment: @Ólafur Waage but do those tell me whether it's friday in iceland or not?  I can tell when it's friday here, but you guy's use some sort of crazy moon time.

Comment: Here, I found it: http://www.isitfriday.in/new_york/  - Unfortunately they don't have http://www.isitfriday.in/iceland/ - I suggest someone submit a bug report.

Comment: GMT with no daylight savings time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a restaurant in Bophut beach, Koh Samui

Any suggestions?

Comment: Haven't been there. So can't help you.

Comment: @Ólafur, wtf?  SO can help *everyone*!

Comment: Doesn't mean it should.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome back, we've missed you!

You may want to catch up on these tags:

- [[unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns)]
- [[waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waffles)]
- [[always-friday-in-iceland](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland)]

And also check the April 1 posts, many of which were deleted but can be seen by 10k users [here in the list of undelete-vote posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days).

Comment: Thanks :) I missed you guys as well.